# Unity android Build IL2CPP Failed

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am trying to build a project in unity Android. But it fails. I m using google firebase GoogleAuth, Mapbox and Firestore in the project. Mapbox is and Firestore working fine in the project work. I was not able to test firebase GoogleAuth because i cant build the project

[image]

This is the error i am getting

Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\d8kzr\libil2cpp.so failed with output:

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionRemoveUserAnchor_mE1FD92C3A1176BE4D5BBFA2E1307DA79FC8733E8':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:22008: undefined reference to `SessionRemoveUserAnchor'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:22008: undefined reference to `SessionRemoveUserAnchor'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_mCFA00970955AE15981753F3BC99F6A85C39D4DB3':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21906: undefined reference to `HitTest'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetLastHitTestResult_m338EF511AA96C338A415FCB55E4685CDF6F9809D':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21918: undefined reference to `GetLastHitTestResult'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSession_m4B30AB46AF233DB8D91F6755536347B1A9E46DF4':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21831: undefined reference to `StartSession'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21831: undefined reference to `StartSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSession_m769A55CE7EE3681FE18774C52476BDBB0B2181E1':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21795: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSession'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21795: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCameraNearFar_m62A01B769941B98EFB75A9580C0E17D54A501E8D':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21976: undefined reference to `SetCameraNearFar'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCameraClipPlanes_m7332AC6519CFC40CB6427648EA755857746AEBEE':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21976: undefined reference to `SetCameraNearFar'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mB4E2138417D862E9E997BBC87ECEC41DAF4A7866':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21813: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21813: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_PauseSession_m0DCF838C9F55C4A53AF1A77659683B91AACA9335':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21897: undefined reference to `PauseSession'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21897: undefined reference to `PauseSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_CapturePixelData_mF3AAC4338F5B9DD8BAE38CF85467074378B81289':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21985: undefined reference to `CapturePixelData'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21985: undefined reference to `CapturePixelData'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetVideoTextureHandles_m1F7A6CECD0C035F6198B065311372B7DEB3D2FB4':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21936: undefined reference to `GetVideoTextureHandles'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_CapturePixelData_mF3AAC4338F5B9DD8BAE38CF85467074378B81289':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21985: undefined reference to `CapturePixelData'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetARVideoTextureHandles_mB7FBE1979920A2A34A26E9602DDBB035DB66A870':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21936: undefined reference to `GetVideoTextureHandles'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_PauseSession_m0DCF838C9F55C4A53AF1A77659683B91AACA9335':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21897: undefined reference to `PauseSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mB4E2138417D862E9E997BBC87ECEC41DAF4A7866':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21813: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSession_m4B30AB46AF233DB8D91F6755536347B1A9E46DF4':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21831: undefined reference to `StartSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionAddUserAnchor_mA41C0D4C95D12B228204A0B7D538A77B6E88961A':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21994: undefined reference to `SessionAddUserAnchor'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21994: undefined reference to `SessionAddUserAnchor'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionRemoveUserAnchor_mE1FD92C3A1176BE4D5BBFA2E1307DA79FC8733E8':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:22008: undefined reference to `SessionRemoveUserAnchor'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetVideoTextureHandles_m1F7A6CECD0C035F6198B065311372B7DEB3D2FB4':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21936: undefined reference to `GetVideoTextureHandles'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `ARFaceAnchor_GetBlendShapesInfo_mFA75CAE01ABC92AD8A771B535BBC0614D7C1808C':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:18798: undefined reference to `GetBlendShapesInfo'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:18798: undefined reference to `GetBlendShapesInfo'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `ARKitSessionConfiguration_IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported_mF3E7BA220D3119C0E9561836E1C8F0A87A7053F6':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20105: undefined reference to `IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20105: undefined reference to `IsARKitSessionConfigurationSupported'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration_IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported_m4552411A33E00768B09F5607EA9F31A0580E59A0':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20238: undefined reference to `IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20238: undefined reference to `IsARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfigurationSupported'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `ARKitFaceTrackingConfiguration_IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported_m0530212FB437B633AF266CEF6719F268E25B2D15':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20349: undefined reference to `IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:20349: undefined reference to `IsARKitFaceTrackingConfigurationSupported'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_unity_CreateNativeARSession_m925851238B94AA807A77833F914198EFF45E0C77':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21687: undefined reference to `unity_CreateNativeARSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetSessionCallbacks_m45AA9EBDFF8CD7E35FB2BF36C3FFB222F930ADF1':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21717: undefined reference to `session_SetSessionCallbacks'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks_m4A78BE45829F4A6F3C91EE904D223B5F921453DB':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21738: undefined reference to `session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetUserAnchorCallbacks_m7FF36BA5583D696D6620C8CC9ED6B31CA3C0B72A':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21759: undefined reference to `session_SetUserAnchorCallbacks'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetFaceAnchorCallbacks_m584E7226761F342730BDAE522B14816D166BD1FC':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21780: undefined reference to `session_SetFaceAnchorCallbacks'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSession_m769A55CE7EE3681FE18774C52476BDBB0B2181E1':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21795: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mB4E2138417D862E9E997BBC87ECEC41DAF4A7866':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21813: undefined reference to `StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSession_m4B30AB46AF233DB8D91F6755536347B1A9E46DF4':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21831: undefined reference to `StartSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSessionWithOptions_m15EA5BB47EEEFAAFF7D41ECAC360DAF5E1762643':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21849: undefined reference to `StartSessionWithOptions'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSession_m45CF13C504D342EBEDC2E2B6DBBCED3A5C95A9B6':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21867: undefined reference to `StartFaceTrackingSession'

Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/o8bn_ly-CSharp1.o: In function `UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions_m68C5AA1F7F46DB342BE503F84B06505F21E47489':

G:/NFT/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/New TheAR-NFT_GPS-SocialMediaFromBackupHardDisk/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:21885: undefined reference to `StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions'

How to fix this error.

Comment: As I see it’s problem with AR sdk. Maybe you use not latest ARCore libraries? Or you AR libraries, which should be added to another platform mistakenly placed in the Android build.